# How to work with Front End developer when you use Django web framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, frontend, backend

I am new to web programming. so I am very confused with concepts.

I understood that Front-End developer and Back-End developer have different duty simply like below.

```
Front-End developer : html css js
Back-End developer : Django Web framework in Server

Back-End developer(Server -> Data) 
Front-End Developer(Data->html with css,js(JQuery,Angular..))
```

I understood that Django framework is coupled with Front-End side. So I would like to send data by django rest framework to spearate duty more clearly(uncoupled way) for front-end and back-end developers.

I thought that if Front-end developer knows information of data **(like below)** which they will get for page(template) or send, They can build up page with html, css, js without any coupled works.

```
{ "id": { "type": "integer", "required": false, "read_only": true, "label": "ID"}
"title": { "type": "string", "required": true, "read_only": false, "label": "Title", "max_length": 200} ... }
```

but I am very confused.

**for example :**

you can get list of users by Get Method example.com/home.(JSON type)
you need to show this lists on template(with html,css,js or JQuery or something).

If you hit example.com, urls config find right view with regex and then render template like below

```
example.com/home -> Server -> url config -> views -> template(render)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^home$'), something_view.as_view()
```

views.py

```
class something_view(generic form or something)
render(request, "something_template.html", Context)
```

something_template.html

To use serializer of django restframework,
you also need to pass through Serializer -> View -> Renderer. it will conflict in views. One url and two views which is related to it...

**You need to show template in django and need to send JSON data to template to show list of users in django restframework module. How can you do that?**

**How can front end developer and back end developer work without much coupled task in Django Framework?**

Well, it could be a ridiculous question. But I am very confused myself with lack of knowledges. I couldn't figure out myself.

Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: I'm not too clear what you're asking, but I haven't met a back end developer yet that had to do some front end stuff. It works the same way as translations, you give someone an outline or "template" if you will, and then they fill in the blanks. Although, our "front end guy" does their share of backend too.. Either way, it sounds like its going to be dependant on company/resources.

Comment: @Sayse Hi. My question would be confusing as much as I am confused myself about work flow when you work with front end developers. First, Django have own template engine. if you use django.form, you just put template syntax {{ form }} in html. front end developer wouldn't know what it is and how to make front page with html, cs, js.

Comment: I thought it is kind of much coupled work with front-end developer if you use many template syntax which have to render by django template engine. so to prevent from coupled work with front-end developer, I thought it would be best choice to send just JSON data. Front end developer knows what data it is such type, name and other requirements. Then they can make front page with html, css, js in a way they want without communicating much with back end developers.

Comment: I am going to use django restframework module. so django restframework would be REST API. but I am confused I can use restframework and django web framework at the same in one server. Is my question getting more clear??? I hope so!

Comment: @Jayground You seem to have some basic confusion as to how to **decouple** backend from frontend. Firstly, it is not _absolutely_ necessary to present your front end using only django templating. You can just as easily create api endpoints using DRF for getting and putting data into your database and do only that using drf, and as far as your frontend is concerned, all it needs is the exact urls from where it can get the data or send the data to. Next, if you really want to deploy frontend using django, create a separate app that hosts the frontend cuz one url can never point to two views.

Comment: @r3ign Thanks for comment!. Yes, I totally misunderstood that django web framework and django restframework share views together. I don't know why I thought like that stupidly.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can almost completely separate the front-end from the back-end.

In our project we have a client folder which contains Angular, CSS, etc., and a server folder which contains Django and DRF.

The only back-end files the front-end guy ever has to touch is 1) the Django index template which is used to load the initial page, 2) the javascript template which contains every JS file, and 3) the CSS template which contains the CSS files.

In reality he only ever touches the javascript template, and that's only when he adds a new JS file.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I see. So if I work as a back-end developer. I write all codes with Django and DRF. for example, if you hit 'example.com/home' in web browser, it shows empty template like just <html><head>empty template</head><body></body>. every urls which is corresponding to views show each empty template. And you have REST API adress with DRF. you can GET some data list as JSON or even you can POST(or UPDATE) through DRF. I write codes for all above.

Comment: At the end, front-end developer know where they need to put static file(html,css,js) and API urls to GET or POST and lastly knows data format for each pages. You can just replace files(static files) in designated folder and check from urls.

Comment: If i understand correctly, it seems enough for front-end developer to work independently from back-end developer??? of course, you will get basic page structure(design for each page). you can build that design in a way you want by using html js css,

Comment: Someone who is just a front-end developer (HTML, CSS and perhaps some basic JS using jQuery or something like that) would most likely only be touching items in the Django templates folder. If the front-end guy wanted to use Angular or React, then the back-end guy would use something like the Django-Rest-Framework (DRF) to talk to Angular.

Comment: I see. Thanks. now I can understand the concept working together with front-end developer and I need to fill something I am still little unsure by experiencing working with them in person.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your actual question is, but for what it is worth, in modern frontend development generally the frontend is a bunch of static files (Javascript, HTML, CSS and whatnot). So there is usually no need for Django templates at all. The project I am working on right now only uses Django template API to generate email messages.

So you define your models using Django model API, then define serializers to convert between python objects and your data format of choice (JSON, XML or whatever), then you define views for your API endpoints. And the front end uses these APIs to save and retrieve data. Libraries like Django REST Framework help the process quite a bit.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answer. Yes my question must be ambiguous for sure. Because I was confused myself. It is getting clear thanks to you guy's comment and answer. So far I understood this way. Lets say that I want to use Django web framework for both front-end and back-end developer together. I make Django framework first. I write urls for each views and then those views render template. I don't use any django own template syntax in template such {% tag %}, {{ value }} and whatever django template engine translate and front-end developer doesn't know.

Comment: Then, I make new app in django and make seriallizer with djangorestframework module and write urls and views to work as REST API. so there are part for just viewing(rendering) html template according to urls and a part for working as REST API in one django web framework at the same time but as different apps inside Django.

Comment: I hope it is right so far. if so, Then, As front-end developer, It is alright to work independently enough from back-end developer, if you know each urls for each templates and JSON(or whatever) data format? I means you can upload html files(static files including image, css, js and so on) through SFTP directly. Back-end developer made all directory structures. just front end developer can replace static files in designated folders.

Comment: Front end developer doesn't even need to know that you are using Django. They don't care. His code makes API calls and gets responses. As long as he knows what APIs to call to do what he wants with the system, he should be fine.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to ask this! So it is standard that front end developer developer independently by just making API calls and getting response? I just experienced building simple pages with PHP and currently Django. If you use some PHP syntax in html or Django syntax in html, It means that work for frontend and backend is coupled together even though those syntax is simple enough to guess what it means. From your answer, I assume that Using Rest API is the normal way and better way to work efficiently???(of course, you can say that efficiency can differ depend on situation but in general)

Comment: Generating pages on the server side has not been popular, since it is almost always easier to send a static page and pull the data needed via AJAX. And if you are not generating pages, there is no reason to use Django or PHP or other templating syntax.